# Google Advertising ID Collision

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-advertising-id

We are having issues with some extreme cases where different users have the same Google Advertising ID. My understanding is that this should never happen in real world, but keep in mind that the app in question has dozens of millions of installations.

Does anyone know if it is possible / expected to have a certain amount of collisions in GAID?

I will keep the GAID partially hidden for privacy purposes but here are some examples:

```
GAID             / Manufacturer / Model       / Collision Amount
5fbfd780-2182    / genymotion   / google_rr_1 / 2224
80cfac86-02e8    / lge          / lg-p760     / 11
80cfac86-02e8    / samsung      / gt-n8005    / 11
80cfac86-02e8    / huawei       / ascend g510 / 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the case in the real world. If you're so afraid that it might affect a big scale production try it on a different real prototype project and not on emulators. As per [Google docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en):

Advertising ID

> **The advertising ID is a unique, user-resettable ID for advertising**,
>   **provided by Google Play services**. It gives users better controls and
>   provides developers with a simple, standard system to continue to
>   monetize their apps. It enables users to reset their identifier or opt
>   out of personalized ads (formerly known as interest-based ads) within
>   Google Play apps.